# Cannot add or insert the item MyFile in more than one place

Tags: c#, winforms

i am build application who play Wireshark files and send the packets to the network card using pcapdot.net.

in my application i get directory root and add only the new files from the last 24 hours.
first i am add all my files from the directory to `List<string>` and then to my `ListView`.
now after my application finished to play all my files i want to clear my List, clear my ListView and again search for now files from the last 24 hours and add to my `ListView`.
my problem is in this spot that after add the files again to my List and try to add file to my `ListView` the application crash with error **Cannot add or insert the item 'file.pcap' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it.**

after finished to play my files i am clean the List, ListView and again add the files and play:

```
            lvFiles.Items.Clear();
            filesList.RemoveRange(0, filesList.Count - 1);
            addFiles();
            playFiles();
```

addFiles(); - aff all the files from List to my ListView:

```
private void addFiles()
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        filesList = SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(pathToSearch, "*.pcap",
            SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
    });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {
            if (filesList.Count != 0)
                AddFilesToListView(filesList);
        });

    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

playFiles() - play all my files in my ListView:

```
private void playFiles()
{
    lockButtons();
    string filePath = string.Empty;
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lvFiles.Items.Count && shouldContinue; i++)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lvFiles.EnsureVisible(i);
                lvFiles.Items[i].Selected = true;
                lvFiles.Select();
                filePath = lvFiles.Items[i].Tag.ToString();
                toolStripStatusLabel.Text = string.Format("Current file: {0}", lvFiles.Items[i].Text);
            });

            PcapFile pcapFile = new PcapFile();
            pcapFile.sendQueue(filePath, adapter);
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lvFiles.Items[i].Selected = false; });
        }
    });
```

add file to my ListView:

```
private void addFileToListBox(string filePath, string duration)
{
    item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { new FileInfo(filePath).Name, duration, "Waiting" });
    item.Tag = new FileInfo(filePath).FullName;
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lvFiles.Items.Add(item); });
}
```

maybe "someone" still hold the file ?

Comment: Show some code. In particular where you are adding to the ListView and clearing the ListView.

Comment: Where do you declare the `ListViewItem` named `item` in the addFileToListBox method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it might be this line that is your problem:

```
item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { new FileInfo(filePath).Name, duration, "Waiting" });
```

That creates a new object but still refers to `item` which by the looks of things is declared in a scope greater than you intended, probably the entire form.

You need to make the objects scope that of the method in which you are adding it to the ListView:

```
        private void addFileToListBox(string filePath, string duration)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { new FileInfo(filePath).Name, duration, "Waiting" });
            item.Tag = new FileInfo(filePath).FullName;
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { lvFiles.Items.Add(item); });
        }
```

If you have declared your variable `item` in a greater scope then every time you create a new ListViewItem you are still actually using the same item in the listview as you were the first time.

While you haven't shown where you declare `item`, you will also need to remove the line where you declare it in the wrong scope:

```
ListViewItem item; // <-- Delete me
```